# ValueError: Graph disconnected. ······ The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I wanted to implement a complex model, but it didn't work and was stuck in the input layer.I've simplified the code, and here's an example:

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K

def build_model():
    label_num = 4
    max_len = 50
    # shape = (B, label_num, max_len)
    label_inputs = Input((label_num, max_len))

    # shape = (B*label_num, max_len)
    reshape_input = Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x, (-1, max_len)))(label_inputs)

    dense = Dense(10)(reshape_input)

    model = Model(reshape_input, dense)
    # do another things
    return model


if __name__ == '__main__':
    build_model()
```

And the errors show that:

```
File "####################\test.py", line 21, in build_model
    model = Model(label_inputs, model1_dense)
  File "####################\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "####################\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 93, in __init__
    self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
  File "####################\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 231, in _init_graph_network
    self.inputs, self.outputs)
  File "####################\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1443, in _map_graph_network
    str(layers_with_complete_input))
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 4, 50), dtype=float32) at layer "input_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

The complex model contains two input tensors with different batch_size, but keras has a batch_size function to check whether every input tensor has the same batch_size. So I must pre-process the data with the same batch_size, after feed to model, I should reshape one of the input tensor like the code above 'reshape_input'.

How can I solve it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: your data should not have batch_size at all. Splitting to batches is a part of keras implementation of stochastic gradient descent. It doesn't relate to data

Comment: I have solved my problem because I use dynamic input layer. Actually, The backgroud of this problem is that, one model for sentece embedding(called sentence_model), another is label embedding(called label_model). And I use network architecture like siamese or triplet for calculating similarity between sentence and labels. A sentence corresponds to a positive_label, in order for the whole model to converge, I should create at least one negative_label sample.

Comment: Assuming that sentence_model has the batch_size called bs, and label_model  will feed one positive_label and n negative_labels, total n+1. So the input data shape will be that [(bs,seq_len),(bs, n+1, seq_len)].

Comment: I should reshape (bs, n+1, seq_len) to (bs*(n+1), seq_len), and feed the data to label_model.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `Model()` call should be `Input()` layer.

Change this line:

```
model = Model(label_inputs, dense)
```

Comment: The comment “The first argument of Model() call should be Input() layer.” reminded me，I should try to make the model have a dynamic input layer in order to reuse.Thank you anyway.